# Java how to save a file with current date and time

Tags: java

I am trying to save the file in the project folder with the current date and time in the name.

My current code

```
     DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("\n dd/MM/yy/ HH:mm:ss");
     Date date = new Date();
     logWriter = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter  ("dd/MM/yy/ HH:mm:ss       serverLog.txt'", true));
```

Below does the job and saves in the write place without date and time

```
     logWriter = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter  ("serverLog.txt", true ));
```

Comment: you have all the data to perform what you what.. have you even tried anything?

Comment: Eh, I see you expect that `FileWriter` should replace `"dd/MM/yy...."` with the date, this won't work.

Comment: Yer i have tried it and it seems not to be working, the file isn't getting saved int he project folder unlike when just name serverlog.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SimpleDateFormat.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH-mm-ss");
Date date = new Date();
logWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(dateFormat.format(date) + " serverLog.log", true));
```

The way you have written it, you try to save the file as ' HH:mm:ss serverLog.txt' in a directory called 'yy', in a directory called 'MM', in a directory called 'dd'; it won't work because colons (`:`) are forbidden in filenames (at least on Windows)  because they mark drive letters.

Comment: Damn, I accidentally submitted the answer half complete. Give me a sec.

Comment: `format.format()` can be confusing. Maybe consider renaming it to something like `formatter.format()`

Comment: Thanks I am getting  15\03\15\ 12:43:51serverLog.txt (The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect)  As before it just saves in the project folder automatically i want this to happen again but cant get that to work when i add time and date

Comment: @Lewis Don't use slashes or colons in your filenames. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Check how you can convert Date to String: http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-convert-date-to-string/

In your case the code should be:

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss");
    Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    String logDate = dateFormat.format(today);
    logWriter = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter(logDate + "serverLog.txt", true));
```

Comment: Hey, I guess you need to edit your solution.

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH-mm-ss");
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
String logDate = dateFormat.format(today);

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy/ HH:mm:ss");
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();        
String date= dateFormat .format(today);

logWriter = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter  (date+" serverLog.txt", true ));
```

There you go!